# How to uninstall Java SE from the command line

Tags: java, uninstall, windows-installer, jre, jdk

Oracle states that the Java SE installer is built using MSI, but [the help page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/silent-136552.html), rather unhelpfully doesn't list uninstall options.

I need to do a command line uninstall, and I can't figure out or find relevant the options for 1.6.21

I've tried wrapping the installer .exe in *msiexec* using `msiexec /q /x <jre>.exe`, but this just reports that the installation package could not be opened.

Running the installer .exe with the `/s /x` option just hangs.

Edited to add:
`msiexec /x {3248F0A8-6813-11D6-A77B-00B0D0160021} /q` => "This action is only valid for products that are urrently installed"

Anyone got the right command line?

Comment: Can't you uninstall it from `Control Panel -> Add/Remove Programs`

Comment: It's for a compute cluster so ideally it needs to be command line uninstall.

Answer (score 10):

You can find the correct product code to pass to `msiexec /x` by opening in the registry (`regedit`).  Open the key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Select the Uninstall key and "Find" from the "Edit" menu.  Search for "Java."  This should show which subkey the Java is located under.  One of the keys is "UninstallString."  Use this command to uninstall Java.  Note however, this will only work on other machines if the exact same version of Java is installed.

Comment: Installing JDK 1.6u21 onto a local PC allowed me to see that the GUID isn't the one I was expecting (based on Oracle docs & Server Fault). A JRE/JDK difference. `reg query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{32A3A4F4-B792-11D6-A78A-00B0D0160210} /v uninstallString `

Comment: hmm, on the compute nodes MSIEXEC reports **that action is only valid for products that are installed** and `reg query /s HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` has no record of the JDK being installed.

Comment: +1 This method worked well to uninstall a botched SQL Server 2012 rsfx driver package.

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall references the 64-bit programs.  It is likely you may also need to check HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\WOW6432Node\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall for 32-bit programs.  Java can be installed as either, or both at the same time

Comment: referencing above registry key, the correct path for my Win10 machine is `REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node\JavaSoft"`  `WOW6432Node` should be after `SOFTWARE`

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 places where you might find the product code:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\4EA42A62D9304AC4784BF238120662FF\InstallProperties
```

or

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

You should be able to find the uninstall string from the key `UninstallString`; something like: `MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83216026FF}`

Answer (score 0):

FYI if you are on Windows Server 2012 Core and trying to find the uninstall string for Java 7, go to following place in the registry to find the uninstall string.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little time consuming, but how about:

```
wmic product where "name like 'java se%'" call uninstall
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the version you have installed on your PC. 
For Java 8 installs, the following is from my batch uninstaller.

```
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_11\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u11...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218011F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_20\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u20...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218020F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u25...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218025F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u31...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218031F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u40...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218040F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u45...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218045F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u51...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218051F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u60...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218060F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u65...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218065F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u66...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218066F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_71\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u71...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218071F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_72\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u72...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218072F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_73\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u73...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218073F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_74\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u74...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218074F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_77\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u77...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218077F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u91...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218091F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u101...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180101F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u111...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180111F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u121...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180121F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u131...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180131F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_141\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u141...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180141F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u144...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180144F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u151...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180151F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_152\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u152...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180152F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u161...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180161F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_162\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u162...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180162F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u171...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180171F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_172\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u172...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180172F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u181...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180181F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u191...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180191F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_192\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u192...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180192F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_201\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u201...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180201F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u202...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180202F0} /Q

IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_11\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u11...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218011F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_20\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u20...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218020F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u25...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218025F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u31...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218031F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u40...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218040F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u45...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218045F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u51...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218051F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u60...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218060F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u65...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218065F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u66...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218066F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_71\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u71...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218071F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_72\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u72...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218072F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u73...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218073F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_74\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u74...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218074F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_77\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u77...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218077F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u91...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218091F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u101...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180101F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u111...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180111F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u121...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180121F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u131...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180131F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_141\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u141...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180141F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u144...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180144F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u151...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180151F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_152\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u152...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180152F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u161...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180161F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_162\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u162...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180162F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u171...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180171F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_172\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u172...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180172F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u181...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180181F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u191...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180191F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_192\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u192...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180192F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u201...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180201F0} /Q
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u202...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180202F0} /Q

IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_11\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u11...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418011F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_20\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u20...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418020F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u25...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418025F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u31...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418031F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u40...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418040F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u45...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418045F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u51...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418051F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u60...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418060F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u65...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418065F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u66...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418066F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_71\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u71...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418071F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_72\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u72...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418072F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u73...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418073F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_74\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u74...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418074F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_77\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u77...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418077F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u91...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418091F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u101...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180101F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u111...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180111F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u121...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180121F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u131...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180131F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_141\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u141...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180141F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u144...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180144F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u151...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180151F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_152\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u152...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180152F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u161...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180161F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_162\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u162...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180162F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u171...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180171F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_172\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u172...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180172F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u181...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180181F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u191...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180191F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_192\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u192...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180192F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u201...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180201F0} /Q
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe" ECHO Uninstalling Java 8u202...&MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180202F0} /Q
```